# Sorting Sankey chart's source & destination nodes alphabetically

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I am creating Sankey chart using Highcharts where I want to sort my source and destination labels alphabetically.
In this image you can see labels are randomly assigned as per data values.
I want to sort those labels for both source and destination. So in second column I want to see nodes in below order,

```
England -> France -> Portugal -> Spain
```

How can sort all nodes to get such result ?

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no special option for sorting by name in a sankey type diagram, the data visualization is based on the flow composition algorithm.

You can easily post-sort by rearranging the data in the correct order according to the keys.to.

```
data: [
  ['Canada', 'England', 1],
  ['Canada', 'France', 5],
  ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1],
  ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5],
  ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
  ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
  ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
],
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f5L3ajy8/2/